# How to Install Debug Symbols for libc on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, apt, debug-symbols

Before Ubuntu 20.04, I can install debug symbols for libc by installing the `libc6-dbg` package (which contains a long list of dynamic libraries compiled with debug symbols as shown in https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libc6-dbg/filelist). However, on later Ubuntu distributions, the `libc6-dbg` package contains only some `*.debug` files, as shown in the two links below.

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/libc6-dbg/filelist
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libc6-dbg/filelist

I also search the debug symbol packages archive (http://ddebs.ubuntu.com) and found nothing.

It seems to be a known issue but without much activity. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1918035)

Is there still a package that gives dynamic libraries with debug symbols for libc on Ubuntu 22.04? Do I have other ways to get the debug symbols besides compiling the libc myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this question, debug symbols have been correctly packed but switch to the new build-id system as the latest update on the BUG tracker says: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1918035. So we need to find debug symbols using build-ids instead of filenames now.